# Ubuntu machine is unable to reboot due mount of drive

Tags: ubuntu, mount, reboot

**Summary**

I have an Ubuntu VM hosted by Azure. About 8 hours ago I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and then `reboot`. Since then I'm only able to access the machine in emergency mode. The only error I can see in output of the reboot is:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /mnt/sdc.
```

**Troubleshooting Steps**

I tried to manually mount this but received the error message `/mnt/sdc: /dev/sdc already mounted or mount point busy`.

I ran `ps aux | grep sdc` and got the following output:

```
root       390  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:34   0:00 [jbd2/sdc1-8]
root      1519  0.0  0.0  14860  1016 ttyS0    R+   14:13   0:00 grep --color=auto sdc
```

So then I tried to kill this process but am unable.

**Question**

If you've been in this situation or understand what's going on could you please help me understand what I need to do? I mounted this drive about 10 months and it hasn't ran into issues since so I am lost here.

**`cat /etc/fstab`**

```
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
UUID=d22737df-af8f-43b8-8146-90f8eb34d05f       /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
UUID=5E59-638A  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults,discard        0 0
/dev/sdc        /mnt/sdc        ext4    defaults        0       0
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig       0       2
//sihstaffstor.file.core.windows.net/sih-workspace /mnt/sih-workspace cifs nofail,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/sihstaffstor.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
UUID=1a3bed40-91a8-4e2a-8092-8ddfe3dcb60b /mnt/sdc1 ext4 defaults,nofail 1 2
```

**`lsblk -f`**

```
NAME    FSTYPE LABEL           UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda     ext4                   d80521c3-0fac-4228-aa39-c2a8db512c72
sdb
└─sdb1  ext4                   1a3bed40-91a8-4e2a-8092-8ddfe3dcb60b /mnt/sdc1
sdc
├─sdc1  ext4   cloudimg-rootfs d22737df-af8f-43b8-8146-90f8eb34d05f /
├─sdc14
└─sdc15 vfat   UEFI            5E59-638A                            /boot/efi
```

**`df -h`**

```
Filesystem                                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                                7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                               1.6G  608K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdc1                                            29G   25G  4.3G  86% /
tmpfs                                               7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                               7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc15                                          105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1                                            32G   49M   30G   1% /mnt
//sihstaffstor.file.core.windows.net/sih-workspace 1000G  635G  366G  64% /mnt/sih-workspace
```

Comment: By unable I mean no matter which `sudo pkill` signal I send the PID changes.

Comment: Please provide `cat /etc/fstab`, `lsblk -f` and `df -h`.

Comment: @cryptarch Added the outputs of these in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may have been an issue within Azure. I resumed troubleshooting this morning and after a reboot the disk was mounted after no config work.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's an issue with an updated package (*presumably anything with device services*) *or* actually an unlucky coincidence with this partition *or* an access violation. But these are shots in the dark without further information.

For possible issues on the **update/upgrade** it's impossible to make a guess without seeing this/ese log/s first: `/var/log/apt/term.log`
*& if necessary* `/var/log/apt/term.log.N.gz` *(where 'N' is a counter)*.

Also the output of `blkid` and `lsblk` (and `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`) might give a clue as /dev/sdc seems to be mounted.

Access violations may occur if you try to mount a ***virtual fs*** (*e.g. .vmdk*) in a VM guest and the physical partition is already mounted by the host. This can happen e.g. unseen and unintended on Windows Hosts as Windows always mounts everything that is (re)connected. So ensure to unmount every disk *from the host* that you want to use within the guest – even if its just a single partition among many.

Disks can die – and they always do when you are sure it's impossible. So test it!
First check the S.M.A.R.T. data (gsmartmontools, GSmartControl, etc.).
If that doesn't clarify it, – *depending on the fs* –, run `chkdsk` or `fsck` **with** surface test (*the latter command will definitely not help on NTFS!*). But this can really take a while.

The point of this is, if there is a damage, in the worst case every further attempt to access this disk can severely damage it even more and you might not be able to rescue your data!!! **So do not try to mount it until you are sure that any other option (e.g. the update) can be excluded!**

I hope this helps for troubleshooting.